# Digital Persona Fingerprint(4500) reader integration with Vue JS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fingerprint

I would like to scan fingerprints via a fingerprint scanner and send the results to my vue js app.

```
<script>
      import '@/assets/js/websdk.client.bundle.min.js';
      import '@/assets/js/fingerprint.sdk.min.js';


      export default {
        mounted() {
          let sdk = new Fingerprint.WebApi
          console.log(sdk)
        },
        methods: {
        }
      };
      </script>
```

i am getting the error

Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: Fingerprint is not defined"

Comment: It's unknown what are these scripts and why you expect Fingerprint.WebApi to exist. In case you lack proper documentation to follow, this boils down to examining these scripts and checking how they work